# working of constructor c++

Tags: c++, constructor

Help me figure out how the line `p1(10,15);` works and From where p1 derive from as it was never declared.
I am learning how constructor works
i used this link [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constructors-c/)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Point
{
    private:
        int x, y;
    public:
    // Parameterized Constructor
    Point(int x1, int y1) 
    { 
     x = x1; 
     y = y1; 
    }

    int getX()       
    { 
        return x; 
    }
    int getY()
    { 
        return y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Constructor called
    Point p1(10, 15); 

    // Access values assigned by constructor
    cout << "p1.x = " << p1.getX() << ", p1.y = " << p1.getY();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Strongly recommend investing in a good book: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @user4581301 I will take a look thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make an instance of class `Point`, it automatically call constructor and do the assignment.

```
Point p1(10, 15);
```

it's like this:

```
Point(10, 15) 
{ 
 x = 10; 
 y = 15; 
}
```

and you using 2 functions to get x,y :

```
cout << "p1.x = " << p1.getX() << ", p1.y = " << p1.getY();
```

Comment: p1 is declared when it is used for calling ?

Comment: It's created when program reach this line  : `Point p1(10, 15);  `